# Lenovo ThinkServer Ubuntu 12 Server Install: Partition Issues

Tags: installation, server, partitioning, raid, lenovo

During the Ubuntu 12 install, I get the a screen that says "ATA RAID Device Detected" and asks if I want to enable it. Having used Lenovo Easy Setup to configure the raid (1 array with 2 1tb drives) I chose "Yes".

It takes me to the Partition manager where I can see three options, and a blank line after the first:

```
* Configure iSCSI
* ___________________
* Undo Partition Changes
* Write changes to disk
```

I have no idea what iSCSI is but I'm pretty sure it's not for me.
Undo partition changes just hangs the system at a purple screen.
Write changes to disk gives me an error stating no root files system is defined.

What should I do to get Ubuntu installed with the RAID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lenovo ThinkServer RD 330 Supports only SUSE, RHEL, and Windows OSs and unofficially supports Nix distros based on the former like CentOS 6.

Sadly, I wasn't here when this machine was purchased or we would have went with something more flexible.

Comment: I've got an RD430 server and it run ubuntu ok. Any issues I've had can be blamed on the RD430's finicky BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Hei man, I had successful install the Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 to my RD330.
The point is error of install grub to the mega raid disk.
The way to get through this problem is :
I suppose your RD330 is the default BIOS setup (include the RAID setup).
And you need a DVD of Ubuntu amd64 installation.

And then you can boot up from the DVD, install the Ubuntu step by step.
In the step of partition, install program will report that it found a ATA-RAID device, you should chose "use it", then you will partition the hard-disk by manual, I use the full disk for `/` directory. You should note that, the disk device file is strange--`/dev/md126p1, /dev/md126p2, /dev/md126p5...`

OK, you should go next, until you got the error "install GRUB to disk" step. Don't worry, just go through, and restart by DVD again.
Once you restart , you should enter the ubuntu command-line mode provided by the DVD.
Now we start to install GRUB by our hand:

```
# mount /dev/md126p1 /target
```

If you had partition the /home to a seperated partition, you should do next:

```
# mount /dev/md126pX /target/home
```

"X" is your partion dev number, you should know it from prev installation process.

```
# mount -o bind /proc /target/proc
# mount -o bind /sys /target/sys
# mount --rbind /dev /target/dev
```

（Now we do a chroot to the mount system.）

```
     # chroot /target /bin/bash
```

(Now create the file device.map, used by GRUB.）

```
# echo "(hd0) /dev/md126" > /boot/device.map
```

NOTE THAT: use `/dev/md126`, NOT `/dev/md126p1`, it should the `md126`!

```
# cp /boot/device.map /boot/grub/
```

Now install grub

```
# grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/md126
# grub-setup /dev/md126
```

# update-grub     grub

It will build the file: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
Done.

The key process is `echo "(hd0) /dev/md126" > /boot/device.map` 
Because the Ubuntu installation program use the `/targe`t partition `/dev/md126p1` directory in grub-install, so it can't be done in a raid. The RAID MBR is not on the first partition `/dev/md126p1`,  but on the base devices file `/dev/md126`.

I had tried weeks for this problem, finally win! Woo!